# jQuery odd/even Selectors for Multiple Elements

Tags: jquery, css

I am using the following code to zebra strip a few tables on one page:

```
    $(".events-table tr:even").css("background-color", "#fff");
$(".events-table tr:odd").css("background-color", "#efefef");
```

This is working just fine, but the even/odd intervals are applied to every table on the page.  I would like each table to have the same pattern.  Meaning, each table should start with the same colour on the first row, then same on the second row, for each table on the page.

Any suggestions?

Thx!

Answer (score 12):

you could probably use a selector for the table and then find the rows to color, ie:

```
$(".events-table").each(function()
{
    $(this).find("tr:even").css("background-color", "#fff");
    $(this).find("tr:odd").css("background-color", "#efefef");
});
```

Comment: or just use `:nth-child(odd|even)` :)

Answer (score 6):

Use [`:nth-child()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/nthChild) (`:nth-child(odd)` and `:nth-child(even)`) as opposed to `:odd` or `:even`

```
$("table.events-table tr:nth-child(even)").css("background-color", "#fff");
$("table.events-table tr:nth-child(odd)").css("background-color", "#efefef");
```

the `:odd` and `:even` are actually 0-based, meaning odd rows are 0,2,4, etc. and vice-versa and are used to get odd and even matches in the complete wrapped set.

Take a look at **[this Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/ihiha)** to demonstrate.

`nth-child()` performs the selection on a parent element basis.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `.events-table tr` selectors returns a list of `tr`s independent of whether they belong to the same table. The `:even` and `:odd` selectors are applied to the complete list.

If you don't have an incredible big amount of tables you could just use ids rather than classes.

```
$("#events-table1 tr:even").css("background-color", "#fff");
$("#events-table1 tr:odd").css("background-color", "#efefef");
$("#events-table2 tr:even").css("background-color", "#fff");
$("#events-table2 tr:odd").css("background-color", "#efefef");
```

Comment: Much better solution, allowed me to selectively choose which tables I wanted formatted this way. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The :odd and :even selectors are jQuery-specific "extensions". As mentioned by bluenote, they seem to operate on a list of *all* elements of the targeted type (in your case, all `tr` in `.events-table`.

Alternatives include:

- Constraining the selector to the table context by passing your table element as the second argument `$('tr:odd', mytable).css({})`
- Using the "real" css nth-child selector `$('.events-table tr:nth-child(even)').css()` though beware of cross-browser compatibility issues.
- Assigning an 'odd' or 'even' class to the appropriate rows and targeting that explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("tr:odd").css("background-color", "#bbbbff");
```

will change odd rows for all the tables on the page, you can put another one for even

Answer (score 0):

Try adding IDs to your tables and updating the CSS one table at a time.